# How can I lock down a user account to the point that it can read/write/execute as little as possible?

Tags: ssh, permissions, security, account-restrictions, accounts

I would like to lock down an Arch Linux user account to the maximum extent possible.  The only functionality required for the account is to accept a non-terminal SSH session which allows the client to create a tunnel to the internet.

The situation is that I want to share my remote connection with a few friends.  I will provide them with an SSH key for the account and configure their programs as necessary.

The complication is that I don't want to place 100% faith in their ability to secure the key file.  I'd rather minimize the potential damage of a compromise while it's still hypothetical - and take the opportunity to learn more about security.

Is there any way I can achieve a completely isolated and/or locked down account?  Can I allow SSH connections but refuse terminal access?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  Thank you for posting it, an Welcome to U&L.SE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add keys to an `authorized_keys` file you have several options to restrict what that key can do. In this situation, you can disallow running any commands. Simply prefix it with `command=""`.

For example:

```
command="" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDc7nKsHpuC6W/U131p0yDh455sLE9pWmFxdK...
```

When the user wants to connect, they have to pass `-N` to `ssh`. This tells the `ssh` client not to try running a command, but to just open a connection (and do tunneling if configured). If the client is started without `-N`, it'll immediately disconnect.

For example:

```
ssh -N -D 8080 host.example.com
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, but how to do this without Auth Keys just normal user and pass.

Comment: for future reference: You can change the shell of a linux user with chsh to /sbin/nologin. That should have the same effect.